# How to open an attachment file that don't have a postfix?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application, its photo files stored in a directory such as `"myhost/attachment/pictures".`

The name of picture files are be named as ids, and don't have any postfix, for example '543cb9fa66041'. Now I want to know how to open the picture files?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What platform are you on?

Comment: @george Do you mean that your image name is not stored with the extension like ".jpg, png"?

Comment: @ Zainul Abideen @haneefmubarak My platform is wamp, yes I mean that my image name  is not stored with the extension like ".jpg, png".

Answer (score 1):

Refer this article http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

you can get file type like image/gif etc. Based on you can open file.